# An exception launched in a Promise is not captured in the catch() method

Tags: javascript, exception, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I throw an exception in the asynchronous code inside the Promise. The exception isn't captured in the `catch()` method

```js
let x = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{setTimeout(()=>{throw new Error(5);},3000)}).catch((error)=>{console.log(error)})
```

Instead with this code:

```js
let x = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{setTimeout(()=>{reject( new Error(5));},3000)}).catch((error)=>{console.log(error)})
```

with the `Error` in the `reject` ,is intercepted in the catch() method.
(I executed the code in the console of my browser, and I observed this behavior)
What does it mean?  Thus, if an exception is launched from `JSON.parse()` and un exception is tried, will not be captured? And if it's like that, how can I handle this situation? I mean this situation, in the case that `JSON.parse()` launch an exception because the format of the file returned from the server isn't properly formatted like JSON.:

```js
function APIRequest(){
return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{

let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status<299 || xhr.status == 304) {
                    let response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    resolve(response);
                } else {
                    reject('something is gone wrong')
                }
}
xhr.open('GET','URL_REQUEST);
xhr.send(null);

});
}
```

(I know that there is `fetch()`, it's an example...)
Should I use a old `try-catch` around `JSON.parse` and in the old catch block do `reject(error)`? Or is there a more clean solution?

Comment: An error is only turned into a rejected promise in an _async_ function.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks. I don't want use async-await costruct.   Thus i should do in my callback: `try{JSON.parse().....other code} catch(e){reject(e)}`

Comment: @jonrsharpe If the error is thrown _synchronously_, then it will reject the promise: `new Promise(() => { throw new Error() })`. Note to OP: you should call `reject` function to reject the promise instead of _throwing_ the error.

Comment: Personally I'd do `const delay = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms)); let x = delay(3000).then(()=>{ throw new Error(5); }).catch((error)=>{ console.log(error) });` so that the error is thrown synchronously within a promise handler.